# Using an updated array of objects inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Within a view I'm using ng-repeat inside a directive to loop over an array of objects from my controller. During this phase the objects inside the array suffer value changes. When I change the view and create a new instance of the same directive, I want to loop over the array of objects yet again but this time loop over the updated array of objects.

If I modify the objects in the first view and pass the same array of objects in the second view, the directive uses the initial array, not the updated one. What I tried is watching the array for changes, it sees the changes but still during the second instance of the directive it uses the initial array.

Can someone explain whats going on and how could I solve this ?

Comment: You need to add a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a simple parent child relationship directive, in which directive have access to scope of controller o the view in which it's added. so you can have ng-repeat in directive & array in scope variable of controller. Then automatically the values will be sync by two way data binding. You can follow following plunk I've created.

It depends upon how are you sharing data between controller & directive. Two data binding helps make it sync else you've to handle it over event or using $watch in directive (if you're using jquery code inside directive).

https://plnkr.co/edit/m47TPgcX7lY8nL1LswCv?p=preview

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function ($compile, CarCompany) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>\
                  <h2>HelloWorld directive</h2>\
                  <p ng-repeat="car in carc">{{car.name}}</p>\
                  <h3>Liste des marques:</h3>\
              </div>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

      var ul = document.createElement('ul');
      var lis = '';
      angular.forEach(CarCompany, function(item) {
        lis += '<li>' + item.name + '</li>';
      });
      ul.innerHTML = lis;

      elem.append(ul);

      $compile(ul)(scope);
    },

  };
});
```

This's simple directive showing shared scope between controller & directive.
https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/11/understanding-scopes-in-angularjs-custom-directives.aspx